# All in one seo pack не выводит description статей

Tags: wordpress

Как заставить хук подтягивать значение description статьи?
Сейчас выводит дефолтное, которое для всех страниц...

Файл functions.php:

```
function my_aiosp_description($my_description) {
    $my_description = 'Мое описание статьи';
  //var_dump($my_description);die();
    return $my_description;
}
add_filter('aioseop_description','my_aiosp_description');
```

При выводе страницы НЕ подставляется мое значение. Если завардампить и вывести значение в хуке, то хук срабатывает и выводит значение:

```
 'Мое описание статьи'
```

а в браузере выводит значение:

```
 'Стандартное описание'
```

(которое вводится в Админка -> Настройки плагина All-in-One-SEO-Pack -> Настройки заголовков -> Формат описания)

Comment: завардампить ))

Comment: @KAGG Design  я вывел Вам значения var_dump!!!

Comment: Смотри в настройках/код темы